# php 5.4 on CentOS7

Tags: centos, php, mediawiki

I am trying to install MediaWiki 1.27 on CentOS7.2. CentOS7.2 comes with php 5.4. However, at least 5.5.9 is required for MediaWiki 1.27.

I have installed and enabled rh-php56 from SCL repo which installed php5.6 in parallel with CentOS stock php5.4.

Unfortunately, MediaWiki still gives me an error that I am running php5.4. Is there a way I can point MediaWiki to start using the newer php5.6 instead? Or am I better off replacing the stock php5.4 with php5.6 from Remi's repository?

Thank you!

Comment: Software Collections being a bit of a pain to work with sometimes, I always use Remi repo. But this is mostly asking for an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

As answered on CentOS [forum](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=59199)

If you use **mod_php** and have both php (base version) and rh-php56-php, only the first will be loaded, so need to be disable (comment the LoadModule in 10-php.conf) or uninstall it

If you use **FPM**, you have to stop php-fpm service and start the rh-php56-php-fpm service.

Comment: I wish I could give you +1000 for being *that* Remi - thank you for all your hard work!  As it is, I can only upvote you; so I have.